# How to Create a bacPac file from PIT Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, point-in-time

I have a requirement to basically beable to 'tag' PIT restores as to hold for longer (and then later use the restore on demand), the only way i can think to do this is basically figure out a way to export the requested Point-in-Time restore to a bacpac and save it in Azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

> PIT restores as to hold for longer.

The Azure SQL Database service protects all databases with an automated backup system. **These backups are retained for 7 days for Basic, 35 days for Standard and 35 days for Premium.**

> I can think to do this is basically figure out a way to export the requested Point-in-Time restore to a bacpac and save it in Azure storage.

These are two different approach. Either you restore a database from PIT or from bacpac file which is either stored in Azure Storage account or local machine.

**You can't perform a Point-of-Time restore from bacpac file.**

Refer [Azure SQL Database Point in Time Restore](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/) and [Export to a BACPAC file - Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql) to know more.